# Gradle Custom Plugin: The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

My custom gradle plugin is as below

```
package my.own.gradle

import org.gradle.api.*

class GroovinPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("groovin", GroovinPluginExtension)
        project.task('groove') << {
            println project.groovin.message
        }
    }
}

class GroovinPluginExtension {
    def String message = 'We be groovin\''
}
```

As per [example](http://malsandroid.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/writing-custom-gradle-plugin-groovy.html). I got a warning:

```
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Need to change the `<<` the to `doLast` as below

```
package my.own.gradle

import org.gradle.api.*

class GroovinPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("groovin", GroovinPluginExtension)
        project.task('groove') {
            doLast {
                println project.groovin.message
            }
        }
    }
}

class GroovinPluginExtension {
    def String message = 'We be groovin\''
}
```